# A fast way to concatenate .png files into an animated GIF?

Tags: web, converters, gif

I am currently using "convert" to convert a set of png files to an animated GIF:

```
  system("convert -delay 4 -loop 0 /tmp/$$/*.png $out");
```

(from a perl script).

This turns out to be quite slow if there are too many PNG files, but it needs to be done "on-demand" from the web. It can take 10 seconds or so, during which the user has to wait.

Is there a better, faster way of concatenating all the PNG files? (Is this slow because of compression to GIF, if so, I don't mind using a faster compression scheme.)